# UISearchDisplayController shift searchBar above frame in iOS6,but ok in iOS7

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I embeded UISearchBar in navigationBar in my viewcontroller. Here is the code .I load SearchBar and UISearchDisplayController programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];


   searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
   searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = NO;



self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;

searchBar.delegate = self;


[self.navigationItem setTitleView:searchBar];

}
```

And in viewWillAppear ,I add background image to my navigationBar.That's it. Not a complex view.   It is working fine in iOS7.  When user tap on SearchBar,it changes to editting mode searchBar is in the same position (x,y) .   But when I tested on iOS6 , when tap on searchBar , we enters the editting mode but searchBar shifting up to above the screen. It is a behavior of searchDisplayController that try to cover view.

How can I solve this ? I tried to search through SO but has no luck so far.

Thanks in advance